# Can you fill in the missing number?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

Try to figure out what **number** might be missing inside circle (sorry for bad drawing :P ) .

[image]

All the best :)

Hint #1

> Solving this puzzle involve addition and subtraction of number of same side or other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On each side, take absolute value of difference in numbers in the corresponding cells. Add these two.
>
> 459-127+98-93 = 337